# step by step debugging error with vivado hls. systemC

Tags: debugging, systemc, vivado

I am using Vivado HLS and even though my project compiles and synthesizes without error, when I try the step by step debugging I get the following error after a couple of steps:

> Can't find a source file at
>   "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\bol\win_build\sc_build\build\obj-MINGW-x86-g++\tools\MINGW-x86\systemc-2.3.0\obj-MINGW-x86-Debug\src\sysc\kernel/../../../../src/sysc/kernel/sc_main_main.cpp"
>   Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its
>   location.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your error message references `C:\MinGW\msys`. This is a system wide MinGW + MSys installation, but Vivado should have its own MSys in `C:\Xilinx\Vivado_HLS\2016.1\msys`. Have you loaded the correct environment? => `.settings64-Vivado_High_Level_Synthesis.bat`

Comment: hey thanks for the input but that was not the case.. the environment was loaded and other project had no problem with debugging. i still haven't figured out an answer

Answer (score 0):

From the error message It seems you are trying to move into SystemC kernel code.
Which might be internal to it's implementation in Vivado.

Instead of stepping into the SystemC kernel code maybe you can try to step-over it, and see if you are able to get through the simulation.